# pandas convert a column of number to 1/-1

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of values named `RSI` and I want to achieve the following effects by means of pandas:

1) If the value of `RSI > 70`, it means that the stock is overbought. So, it may go down in near future (indicating opinion '-1’)

2) If the value of `RSI < 30`, it means that the stock is oversold. So, it may go up in near future (indicating opinion ‘+1’).

3) For the values which between `(30, 70)`, if RSI at time ‘t’ is greater than RSI at time ‘t-1’, the opinion on trend is represented as ‘+1’ and vice-a-versa.

What should I do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import random
RSI = pd.Series(np.random.randn(50))
t = pd.Series(list(range(50)))
opinion = 0
for i in t:
    if i!=0:
        if RSI[i] > 70:
            opinion -=1
        elif RSI[i] < 30:
            opinion += 1
        elif RSI[i] > RSI[i-1]:
            opinion += 1
        elif RSI[i] < RSI[i-1]:
            opinion -= 1

print(opinion)
```

That's if you want a counter to be accumulating along time t whether or not its a buy (+1) or a sell (-1). 
If you want to make a graph of that change, store those values in a Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import random
RSI = pd.Series(np.random.randn(50))
t = pd.Series(list(range(50)))
opcount = 0
opinion =[]
for i in t:
    if i!=0:
        if RSI[i] > 70:
            opcount -= 1
            opinion.append(opcount)
        elif RSI[i] < 30:
            opcount += 1
            opinion.append(opcount)
        elif RSI[i] > RSI[i-1]:
            opcount += 1
            opinion.append(opcount)
        elif RSI[i] < RSI[i-1]:
            opcount -= 1
            opinion.append(opcount)

opinion = pd.Series(opinion)

print(opinion)
```

If you just want an array of +1, -1, 0, do the same but without the += or -=.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
import random
RSI = pd.Series(np.random.randn(50))
t = pd.Series(list(range(50)))
opinion =[]
for i in t:
    if i!=0:
        if RSI[i] > 70:
            opinion.append(-1)
        elif RSI[i] < 30:
            opinion.append(1)
        elif RSI[i] > RSI[i-1]:
            opinion.append(1)
        elif RSI[i] < RSI[i-1]:
            opinion.append(-1)
        else:
            opinion.append(0)
    else:
        opinion.append(0)

opinion = pd.Series(opinion)

print(opinion)
```

Then you can graph that to show like a buy or no buy over time. This is assuming your column of RSI is the value of a stock over time, if each RSI is a different stock, then just do this but for each array in your column.